# Copy war file from local machine to docker

Tags: tomcat, docker

I am using docker and created a tomcat container which is running fine.
But I am not sure how to copy a war file in webapps folder of tomcat container.

Please help!

Thanks,
Yash

Answer (score 4):

Multiple solution :

- Mounting an ssh server on your container and sending the files via
  scp. (**non-recommended** if you don't already use ssh for something else)
- Adding the file during the building process (via Dockerfile and ADD https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add)
- Sharing a volume between host and container. ( run -v command. More info
  https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)

Comment: I would recommend against the SSH option. Also, there is the option of deploying to Tomcat through its http front end: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely

Comment: Edited to add more information about ssh and his use.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. build a new image with a Dockerfile based on your tomcat image and use the ADD command. Then start it
2. use a volume which points to a local directory in which you put the war, the run the container which probably starts tomcat
3. use a volume and use a data container to manage the data in it. Most advanced, but also the most compliant with Docker philosophy. For more information on this, please see https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/

Comment: Well i guess our answer are the same.

Comment: we typed at the same time :D, I would never propose SSH though (since it's heavy and not needed for this use case), so I'll keep my answer here

Comment: If he use boot2docker the file must be on the boot2docker vm right ?

Comment: I haven't yet used boot2docker, since I develop on Linux, but I would suppose so (for case 2). Using ADD in combination with boot2docker is a basic operation, so I would guess he can already do that. Method 3 circumvents this matter completely.

Comment: Related to previous matter : https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#folder-sharing

Comment: Hi All,Thanks a lot for responses , actually my bad that I forgot to mention I am using boot2docker in windows. Having trouble copying any file from my local machine to boot2docker.. please let me know if there is a solution to that. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3273905 Please read the link by Regan posted before your question